# Jenkins maven java 7 permission issue

Tags: java, jenkins, maven

I'm getting this error when attempting a Maven build in Jenkins,

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxxprojectnamedeletedforprivacyxxxx
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-3.x.jar
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1079)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:247)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1202)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteContentsRecursive(FilePath.java:1211)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1193)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteContentsRecursive(FilePath.java:1211)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1193)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$1000(FilePath.java:191)
    at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1172)
    at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1169)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:989)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1169)
    at hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.performInstallation(JDKInstaller.java:130)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:107)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:205)
    at hudson.model.JDK.forNode(JDK.java:130)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.getEnvironment(AbstractProject.java:351)
    at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:2219)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:917)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractMavenBuild.java:56)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.getEnvironment(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:167)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:977)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:484)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1718)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have follow the links and they own by root but with 777 permissions so enable for everyone to follow the link, the real file is read for everyone.. so not sure why is this happening.
any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Do you run Jenkins manually or via service?

It's not recommended to run it manually via `java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war` but with `service jenkins start|stop`.

When you manually start, it'll change owner to user which started `jenkins.war` via `java`, service runs under user:group `jenkins:jenkins`.

Default path for service Jenkins (Debian/Ubuntu) should be `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/<ProjectName>/workspace` and everything inside `/var/lib/jenkins/` must be owned by user `jenkins` and group `jenkins`:

```sh
chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/
```

Also check if you have a properly installed and configured JDK inside your Jenkins project.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to delete a file as part of your build:

`at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1079)`

You will need to adjust your permissions accordingly to allow for write access as well on the parent path and the file(s) in question.  Personally I would recommend you set the owner to the same user that Jenkins runs as and use `chmod -R u+w,go-w <directory>` to set the permissions to only allow that user to make modifications.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your help. this is on a ubuntu 14.04 so runs as user jenkins. so when you say <directory> you mean the jenkins workspace directory for the project?

Comment: In the general case yes, in a more broad case you probably want to do that on the workspace directory itself (the parent of the project directories)

Comment: Thanks. I have to change the location of the workspace dir anyways since now is on the main HD, going to mount another HD and make that the workspace since that can get very big fast.. :) I will do the change and make sure the user is jenkins and group jenkins and will report back. hope this will fix the build error

Comment: hmm no luck. Building in workspace /workspace/workspace/mydir  this have jenkins:jekins permissions all the way to the top dir.. ls -alh /workspace/
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x  4 jenkins jenkins   34 Jan 29 19:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root    root    4.0K Jan 29 18:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins   35 Jan 29 18:56 workspace

Comment: add I went into the directory and is empty... so aparently it did not write anything.. as you can see jenkins is running as user jenkins jenkins   1122     1  0 18:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080

Comment: The other half of the equation is where your JDKInstaller is trying to install your desired JDK version.  You may want to A) adjust where it wants to install, and B) ensure it also is owned by the jenkins user and has the same permissions.

Comment: yes thanks I was noticing I was missing the JDK and JAVA_HOME let me report back.. project is building so far

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it looks like maven was installed likely by root, and thereby owned by root.

If jenkins was installed via any package manager, likely it is running as a "jenkins" user which won't have access to that maven installation.

Just a thought - why not configure jenkins to install/manage the version of maven you'd like to use?

Jenkins will put the maven version you're looking for in a location (based off of the /tools path) which it will have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder in `/opt` and set permissions, but this path must be configured in your Jenkins:

```sh
sudo mkdir /opt/deploy_jenkins
sudo chmod -R a+rw deploy_jenkins/
```